# Autodesk forge viewer: Is there a way to increase the timeout of viewer to load multiple models/large models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using forge viewer 7 version to load the models, sometimes when it takes more time to load them, either due to slow network or due to large models, the viewer looks like getting Timeout and says 'Disconnected'. Is there a way to increase this timeout?

I tried to find the viewer timeouts in documentation but couldn't find.

Error I am getting is "Disconnected!"

Answer (score 0):

Afraid the connection was timed out on a networking level (browser/server shutting the connection down) so there's very limited control over that for Viewer or Javascript.

However you can set up a proxy service (see an example [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/securing-your-forge-viewer-token-behind-proxy-net)) in your backend to relay the requests to and from Forge endpoints - this way you'd have control over the timeout settings in your backend and have the opportunity to optimize network traffic (backend server locality, SD-WAN etc comes to mind) or even cache the request contents to boost performance.

And when you said `sometimes` I suppose the model can be loaded properly when the networking conditions are better - if that's the case you can also consider caching the requests in the browser - see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows) for details.